# Bash sorting comma delimited columns numerically and then alphabetically

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm trying to sort 3 columns numerically in reverse (descending) by the third column first and then sort by the first column alphabetically (to break ties). Entries are delimited by commas(`,`).

For example, my dataset is:

```
y,5,50
x,10,50
z,4,100
```

Expected output:

```
z,4,100
x,10,50
y,5,50
```

However the output I am getting is:

```
z,4,100
y,5,50
x,10,50
```

I am using:

```
sort -t, -k3,3 -n -r -k1,1 filename
```

Not sure why this is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to replace `-k3,3 -n -r` by `-k3,3nr`:

```
sort -t, -k3,3nr -k1,1 file
```

Output:

```
z,4,100
x,10,50
y,5,50
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason what you're suggesting doesn't work is becuase you've applied the flags `-n`, `-r` globally hence the alphabetical sorting is also `-r`eversed. To apply the flag on a per key basis, use:

```
sort -t, -k3,3nr -k1,1 filename
```

This gives the expected output:

```
z,4,100  
x,10,50  
y,5,50
```